# Sequential-ish nature of JavaScript with a for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, sequential

Since JavaScript is sequential (not counting async abilities), then why does it not "seem" to behave sequential as in this simplified example:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Run" onclick="run()"/>
```

JS:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('input');

var run = function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log('Running...');
    var then = Date.now();
    btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

    // Button doesn't actually get disabled here!!????

    var result = 0.0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        result = i * Math.random();
    }

    /*
    *  This intentionally long-running worthless for-loop
    *  runs for 600ms on my computer (just to exaggerate this issue),
    *  meanwhile the button is still not disabled
    *  (it actually has the active state on it still
    *  from when I originally clicked it,
    *  technically allowing the user to add other instances
    *  of this function call to the single-threaded JavaScript stack).
    */

    btn.removeAttribute('disabled');

    /*
    *  The button is enabled now,
    *  but it wasn't disabled for 600ms (99.99%+) of the time!
    */

    console.log((Date.now() - then) + ' Milliseconds');
};
```

Finally, what would cause the disabled attribute not take effect until *after* the for-loop execution has happened?  It's visually verifiable by simply commenting out the remove attribute line.

I should note that there is no need for a delayed callback, promise, or anything asynchronous; however, the only work around I found was to surround the for-loop and remaining lines in a zero delayed setTimeout callback which puts it in a new stack...but really?, setTimeout for something that should work essentially line-by-line?

What's really going on here and why isn't the setAttribute happening before the for loop runs?

Comment: The browser doesn't render changes to the DOM until the function returns.

Comment: This allows the function to make lots of changes, and you don't see them all changing incrementally. When it returns, the updated DOM is rendered in one step.

Comment: @Barmar That makes perfect sense.  Thank you.  Do you have an ECMAScript link or other place for an official reference and more details on that process?

Comment: It doesn't update the DOM because it is STILL running your code... it may also have to do several other things in its queue before it gets to disabling your button, there's no telling. There's only one thread (most of the time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The browser doesn't render changes to the DOM until the function
>   returns. - @Barmar

Per @Barmar's comments and a lot of additional reading on the subject, I'll include a summary referring to my example:

- JavaScript is single threaded, so only one process at a time can occur
- Rendering (repaint & reflow) is a separate/visual process that the browser performs so it comes *after* the function finishes to avoid the potentially heavy CPU/GPU calculations that would cause performance/visual problems if rendered on the fly

Summarized another way is this quote from http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth#javascript-execution-and-rendering

> In most browsers, rendering and JavaScript use single event queue. It means that while JavaScript is running, no rendering occurs.

To explain it another way, I'll use the *setTimeout* "hack" I mentioned in my question:

1. Clicking the "run" button puts my function in the stack/queue of things for the browser to accomplish
2. Seeing the "disabled" attribute, the browser then adds a rendering process to the stack/queue of tasks.
3. If we instead add a *setTimeout* to the heavy part of the function, the setTimeout (by design) pulls it out of the current flow and adds it to the end of the stack/queue. This means the initial lines of code will run, *then* the rendering of the disabled attribute, *then* the long-running for-loop code; all in the order of the stack as it was queued up.

Additional resources and explanations concerning the above:

- [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)
- [Painting](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Painting)
- [Reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow)

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency reasons, the browser does not immediately layout and display every single change you make to the DOM instantly right when the change is made.  In many cases, DOM updates are collected into a batch and then updated all at once at some later time (like when the current thread of JS finishes).

This is done because if a piece of Javascript is making multiple changes to the DOM, it is very inefficient to relayout the document and then repaint each change as it occurs and much more efficient to wait until the Javascript finishes executing and then repaint all the changes at once.

This is a browser-specific optimization scheme so every browser makes their own implementation decisions on exactly when to repaint a given change and there are some events that can cause/force a repaint.  As far as I know, this is not an ECMAScript-specified behavior, just a performance optimization that each browser implements.

There are some DOM properties that require a finished layout before the property is accurate.  Accessing these properties via Javascript (even just reading them) will force the browser to do a layout of any pending DOM changes and will usually also cause a repaint.  One such property is `.offsetHeight` and there are others (though all in this category have the same effect).

For example, you can probably cause a repaint by changing this:

```
btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

to this:

```
btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
// read the offsetHeight to force a relayout and hopefully a repaint
var x = btn.offsetHeight;
```

This [Google search for "force browser repaint"](https://www.google.com/search?q=force%20browser%20repaint&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS515US515&oq=force%20browser%20repaint) contains quite a few articles on this topic if you want to read about it further.

In cases where the browser still won't repaint, the other work-arounds are to hide, then show some element (this causes layout to be dirty) or to use a `setTimeout(fn, 1);` where you continue the rest of your code in the setTimeout callback - thus allowing the browser a chance to "breathe" and do a repaint because it thinks your current thread of Javascript execution is done.

For example, you could implement the `setTimeout` workaround like this:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('input');

var run = function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log('Running...');
    var then = Date.now();
    btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

    // allow a repaint here before the long-running task
    setTimeout(function() {

        var result = 0.0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            result = i * Math.random();
        }

        /*
        *  This intentionally long-running worthless for-loop
        *  runs for 600ms on my computer (just to exaggerate this issue),
        *  meanwhile the button is still not disabled
        *  (it actually has the active state on it still
        *  from when I originally clicked it,
        *  technically allowing the user to add other instances
        *  of this function call to the single-threaded JavaScript stack).
        */

        btn.removeAttribute('disabled');

        /*
        *  The button is enabled now,
        *  but it wasn't disabled for 600ms (99.99%+) of the time!
        */

        console.log((Date.now() - then) + ' Milliseconds');
    }, 0);

};
```

Comment: No idea. I balanced it for you. Another possible way of doing a re-layout, that is of course a bit heavier, is to place the rest of your code inside of `setTimeout()`, with no second argument. I've done that in cases where, for instance, you want something's styles to be applied, and *then* transitioned to another style state (using CSS3 transitions)

Comment: @Katana314 - agree on the `setTimeout()` option - I have that in my answer now too (probably added it while you were reading).  I've used it for CSS3 transitions too.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Thanks for the information. It was just the "why" that I was looking for. In one of my paragraphs I already included the setTimeout solution as a workaround.